# Surface Pro 3 randomly goes to sleep while I'm using it

Tags: sleep, microsoft-surface-pro

As per [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/4rr10q/screen_keeps_unexpectedly_going_into_connected/), 2 other users and myself (and indeed I've had this on completely different Lenovo machine) are having an issue where the Surface will put itself to sleep even while being used. The System event log shows the following Kernel-Power entry:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          20/07/2016 12:27:34
Event ID:      506
Task Category: (157)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (70368744177664),(4)
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      %COMPUTERNAME%
Description:
The system is entering connected standby 

Reason: SC_MONITORPOWER.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>506</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>157</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000400000000004</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-20T10:27:34.006195700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>31798</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="11940" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>%COMPUTERNAME%</Computer>
    <Security UserID="%SID%" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="Reason">3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

My power settings are currently configured like so:
[image: Power settings]

The only time I've noticed it do this erroneously has been when I've been using it. I have no idea if it is doing it when I'm not using it, but have otherwise intended for it to stay on.

Has anyone seen this issue before? Anyone been able to *solve* this issue before?

Comment: Very old, but this seems like it could be related to this: https://superuser.com/questions/1461052/surface-pro-6-goes-standby-every-30min-ish-sc-monitorpower

Comment: @DavidFraser good spot - I think you're probably correct; my Surface Pro 3 doesn't hold charge much anymore and I don't really use it; but if I do, I'll keep this in mind!