# Surface Pro 6 goes Standby every 30min-ish (SC_MONITORPOWER)

Tags: windows-10, standby, microsoft-surface-pro

My Surface Pro 6 behaves weirdly ever since I had it, but I can't really figure out why.

Sometimes during the day or mostly during the evening the system goes in standbymode. It happens every 30minutes in some timeframes but not continously through the whole day.

Let me show you what I mean with a Screenshot of the Event-Viewer:

[image]

I've filtered the events 506 and 507 to gather a more complete example. If you care to look through that, then look here [filebin/SC_MONITORPOWER.zip](https://filebin.ca/4oLiBih6jdUS/SC_MONITORPOWER.zip), but the above screenshot should suffice.

What I don't understand is that I don't have any automatic standby-features activated and I'm also not idle when it happens. The event triggers quite strictly, even while I'm typing.

My Energyplan settings are all set to "Never". You can see that in the screenshots below (I apologize for the german text, it should however still convey the proof of automatic standby being disabled)

[image]
[Advanced Energy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM9Ay.png)

It also doesn't matter if I'm plugged in or using the battery, it happens in both scenarios.

The problem I have with this is that I don't know how to figure this problem out. Looking in the windows documentation of [WM_SYSCOMMAND](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) at least tells me what exactly SC_MONITORPOWER does, but consulting google for any solutions didn't help me at all.

At this point I just don't know where to look.

**Are there other event-view messages that could help me identifying what actually triggers SC_MONITORPOWER in the first place? And why it happens so rythmically?**

---

**Additional System Info:**

Surface Pro 6 / 16GB RAM / 512 GB SSD

System-SKU  Surface_Pro_6_1796_Commercial

Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134 (x64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have set the Sleep setting to never. As a further step, on the same window, in the same list, there should be an option for the video card as well. Just to be sure, set that one to maximum performance. Another thing I can think of, is if there is any surface specific battery saver software, one that would come pre-installed, which overwrites the settings you already changed. Might be good idea to check that too.

Actually, I have looked more into it. It seems very likely that your problem comes from the Windows "Connected standby" feature. For some reason many surface devices have problem because of this feature. What you can try is to disable this feature. For many it seems that it fixed their strange behaviors on the surface. Here is a link to [toolofgod](http://toolofgod.com/problems-and-solutions/disabling-connected-standby-fixed-my-surface-pro-4-problems/) it explains in detail how this feature can be disabled.

The instruction for disabling it:
"Open regedit then navigate to
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\CsEnabled

If you have Connected Standby enabled, this variable will have a 1 (one) in it. To disable it, double-click on the CsEnabled variable and put a 0 (zero) in there. Reboot and you are done."

Comment: There are no options for the video card. (the surface pro 6 only uses the integrated cpu graphics)
In the "Advanced Energy Settings" there's also no category for graphics card.
Regarding battery saving software I would agree but this problem occurs also during charging, meaning when power comes from mains. Do you maybe have a certain software in mind that I can ask microsoft about?

Comment: I see. Not really, I know of some laptop's own battery saver software, for Microsoft specifically sadly I do not know. It might be a way long shot, but you by any chance happen to use an app for taking regular pauses? With such a soft I could the chance to do something like this. Else sadly the old try to do a clean Windows install solution comes only to my mind.

Comment: Nah, definitly not going to do a clean windows install. There must be some kind of reason for this and who says it won't be the same after the install? That just makes me do hours of setting up everything while risking that it might not even work. Sadly, no software like that around. Maybe I should hit the windows forums.

Comment: You're my hero! That sounds exactly like my problem at hand. Didn't see at first that you updated your answer but thanks a lot that you did. That article is worth gold. Not to mention that NOW after having disabled "Connected Standby" I am able to use way more energy options than before.

Comment: I am glad I could help and that your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I had a sort-of similar problem with a Surface Pro 3.  Here's my story:

I had the system set up to never go to sleep while on AC power. I had done this to enable Retrospect backups at 2am and the wake-on-lan was not working since it was on a wifi connection. (Sleeping was killing the wifi and WOL only works on LANs.)

The system was also set to turn off the screen after 10 minutes.

So everything was fine for several years.

The other day Windows 10 Upgrade 1903 was auto-applied and right after that my Retrospect backups started timing out trying to connect to the machine. After some digging I found out that the machine was entering Connected Standby (aka Instant Go) about 45 seconds after the screen was timed out (after 10 minutes) DESPITE the fact that the Power Options were still set to never sleep.

So.  What I discovered is that Update 1903 "improved" Connected Standby by using it all the time despite the power option being "Never Sleep". I have been unable to get it to stop doing this and go back to the pre-1903 behavior which was correct. I used the above-mentioned disabling of CSEnabled and the problem has gone away.  But the downside of doing this is that now there are no sleep options at all.  I have lost the ability to sleep when on DC power.  Given the choice I'll stick with turning off CSEanabled, but its not an ideal solution. The correct solution is for Microsoft to fix update 1903 to restore it to its prior behavior.

Comment: Yea, I agree with you.
This function has caused me nothing but troubles. @AnneKate's solution worked for me to about 80%, but every now and then I still am experiencing random lock-screens appearing that I can escape out of immidiatly.. It's annoying to say the least. But thanks to the answer it happens way less, because before it really was on-time, every 30minutes. Her answer basically is disabling CSE, if I understood what you wrote correctly. I'll open up an issue with Microsoft soon, currently I'm just a tad too busy to do that though.

Comment: Quick Note: I really don't need this function at all. Basically I'm a power user on this machine and power savings mostly cause issues for me, so I want them all turned off. What I need is my surface to turn off (or go in standby) when I press the power button or close the lid and then wake-up again if I open it again. If the machine is on, I'm working on it, so yea... Probably one of the very very few microsoft things that really bother me.

Comment: Agreed.  Me too.